# Can "roof" be used as a synonym for "ceiling"?

Tags: word-usage

I think you use ceiling when you're inside the house and roof when you're outside? Maybe I'm wrong?

Example sentence:

> "I see," my wife said, addressing the ceiling.

Comment: Have you consulted a dictionary? What does it say?

Comment: "the structure forming the upper covering of a building or vehicle." I'm still not very sure ...

Comment: If one dictionary is unclear, try a second one. There are many on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

In certain circumstances they can be interchanged, but those tend to be very specific.

The usual understanding of "roof" and "ceiling" can be found in the dictionary and the comments are pointing you in that direction.

Both a roof and a ceiling are located overhead (assumption of position of viewer).

> a roof

is the surface of the top of the structure of a house when viewed from above.

> a ceiling

is the surface above you when inside a structure.

If one is "dancing on the roof" one is right side up, however, if one is "dancing on the ceiling" one is presumed to be upside down.

Inside a tunnel, its "ceiling" can also be called its "roof".

"Ceiling" also has the meaning of "altitude".  Airplanes have a maximum "ceiling" where they can normally fly, if you reach maximum altitude you can be said to be "roofing it".

> go through the roof
>   break through the ceiling

both phrases have the meaning of moving higher in a dramatic fashion and either can be used depending on context.

> hit the ceiling
>   hit the roof

both are synonymous with being very angry.